# Issue with OR in a MySql query

Tags: mysql

I have an issue with performance when I enhance the query with an OR.

A simplified version of the query is below. Using a form the user can add multiple conditions to the query to narrow their results.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT DocL.DocumentLineId
 FROM DocumentLine            AS  DocL
 INNER JOIN DocumentField     AS DocF00 ON DocF00.DocumentLineId   = DocL.DocumentLineId
 INNER JOIN DocumentField     AS DocF01 ON DocF01.DocumentLineId   = DocL.DocumentLineId

 WHERE ( DocF00.DocumentType_FieldId = '383' AND DocF00.DocumentFieldValue = '113563' )
    OR ( DocF01.DocumentType_FieldId = '383' AND DocF01.DocumentFieldValue = '46910043' )
 ;
```

If I run the query without the last line with the OR it takes less than a second.
With the OR line in the query takes about 45 seconds.

The DocumentLine table has some 75,000 records.

The DocumentField table has some 1.1 million records.

Other than the primary keys on the two tables for their respective Ids, DocumentField has indexes on DocumentLineId, DocumentType_FieldId and DocumentFieldValue.

All Id fields as INT(11).

There are roughly 150 possible values for the DocumentType_FieldId.

DocumentFieldValue is VARCHAR(250) and can contain just about anything.

Any suggestions on how to optimise this query will be much appreciated.

ETA: Performance Data as images on links.

[Explain without the OR line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOCmJ.png)
.

[Explain with OR line added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkYgf.png)
.

```
CREATE TABLE  `DocumentLine` (  
`DocumentLineId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
`DocumentLineSequence` int(11) NOT NULL,  
`DocumentLineCoordinates` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,  
`DocumentLineElementId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,  
`DocumentType_LineId` int(11) NOT NULL,  
`DocumentSectionId` int(11) NOT NULL,  
PRIMARY KEY (`DocumentLineId`),  
KEY `fk_DocumentLine_DocumentSection` (`DocumentSectionId`),  
KEY `fk_DocumentLine_DocumentTypeLine` (`DocumentType_LineId`),  
CONSTRAINT `fk_DocumentLine_DocumentSection` FOREIGN KEY (`DocumentSectionId`) REFERENCES `DocumentSection` (`DocumentSectionId`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE,  
CONSTRAINT `fk_DocumentLine_DocumentTypeLine` FOREIGN KEY (`DocumentType_LineId`) REFERENCES `DocumentTypeLine` (`DocumentTypeLineId`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION);

CREATE TABLE  `DocumentField` (  
`DocumentFieldId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
`DocumentFieldValue` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,  
`DocumentFieldCoordinates` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,  
`DocumentType_FieldId` int(11) NOT NULL,  
`DocumentLineId` int(11) NOT NULL,  
`ElementId` int(11) NOT NULL,  
PRIMARY KEY (`DocumentFieldId`),  
KEY `idx_DocumentType_FieldId` (`DocumentType_FieldId`),  
KEY `idx_DocumentLineId` (`DocumentLineId`),  
KEY `idx_DocumentFieldValue` (`DocumentFieldValue`),  
KEY `idx_TypeId_Value` (`DocumentType_FieldId`,`DocumentFieldValue`));
```

PS: This is the first time that I have asked a question on Stack Overflow so apologies in advance if I have not followed protocol.

Comment: Show actual query not simplified version.

Comment: Why are you joining 2 times on DocumentField?

Comment: An EXPLAIN and CREATE statements are a minimum requirement for questions about query performance. As a minor point, if ids are int, don't compare them with strings (383, not '383')

Comment: The full query simply joins a number of higher tables and has minimal influence on the speed of the query.  The part selected is what causes the performance bottle neck.

Comment: Double, or potentially more joins on that table allow for selecting different criteria.  e.g. 383 might be the Vendor Name while 384 might be the Invoice Amount.

Comment: Added EXPLAIN for both forms of the query.  I take your point on the int for the ids and will adjust in the code.

Comment: Curiously, I would have thought that `(DocumentLineId, DocumentType_FieldId)` would form the composite index - even to the point of dispensing with the surrogate PRIMARY KEY altogether !?!?!

Comment: You and me both, that's why the composite was put there, but no dice :(

Comment: what errors you got on executing this.?

Comment: @Ajay, No errors, it just takes a long time to execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need two joins to get what you want.
Try this:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT dl.DocumentLineId
FROM DocumentField AS df
INNER JOIN DocumentLine AS dl ON dl.DocumentLineId = df.DocumentLineId
WHERE df.DocumentType_FieldId = 383
    AND (
           df.DocumentFieldValue = '113563'
        OR df.DocumentFieldValue = '46910043'
    )
;
```

If you only want to get *DocumentLineId* but nothing else from *DocumentLine* table, then you don't need a join at all:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT df.DocumentLineId
FROM DocumentField AS df
WHERE df.DocumentType_FieldId = 383
    AND (  
           df.DocumentFieldValue = '113563'
        OR df.DocumentFieldValue = '46910043'
    )
;
```

There is also no problem if we want to search different field types (*DocumentType_FieldId*) and use *LIKE*:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT df.DocumentLineId
FROM DocumentField AS df
WHERE ( df.DocumentType_FieldId = '383' AND df.DocumentFieldValue LIKE '%113563%' )
   OR ( df.DocumentType_FieldId = '384' AND df.DocumentFieldValue LIKE '%46910043%' )
   OR ( df.DocumentType_FieldId = '123' AND df.DocumentFieldValue LIKE '%SMITH%' )
   OR ( df.DocumentType_FieldId = '234' AND df.DocumentFieldValue LIKE '%what%ever%' )
;
```

You can join it with *DocumentLine* table if you need more fields from it. You will still get the result in almost no time.

Comment: You are right to a point, my example should have used different values of DocumentFieldValue. If you replace the second 383 ( Vendor Number) with 384 (Vendor Name) then unfortunately you answer is no longer going to work.  The conditions are built up on a form where the user can chose the a field type e.g. Vendor Name, a condition e.g. = and a value to search for e.g. SMITH.  It will probably get worse if they had selected LIKE instead of = and put in %SMITH% for the value.

Comment: HI guys, thanks for all of the help.  I have re-written the query generation so that it only has one instance of the DocumentField table as per Pauls' answer.  I still believe that MySQL should be smart enough to work out the optimisation where the same table is used multiple times.  I have certainly used that feature where I have wanted to get multiple fields on the same row but with different descriptions and it has worked well.  Thanks, Derek.